# Read updated text file every x seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, coordinates

I am working on making a program that is going to read xy coordinates in a text file from a drawing application. I am thinking that the sets of coordinates will start getting detected from the start to the end of the drawn line. For each line drawn there is gonna be a new set of xy coordinates. Then I want to make a program that is

1. Going to look for updated sets of xy coordinates every x seconds
2. If the text file is updated I want the new contents of the text file to be written in the console
3. If the file is not yet updated I don't want it to do anything

Also I am wondering if the best thing is to

1. Have a single text file that get its contents changed with the new set of xy coordinates?
2. Or to have a single text file that get the new set of xy coordinates addes to the previous sets of coordinates?
3. Or have a new text file to be created for every new set of xy coordinates?

I am really new to programming and would really appreciate if I got some kind of help. I have been programming in C# in Visual Studio. I am pretty sure I need to use FileSystemWatcher, I just don't know how to use it....

So far I have only done this:

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This file doesn't excist:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }


            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can,use a database. Checking a file every fews sceconds is going to lead to file locks sooner or later. For example, if you try to update file while the streamreader is reading it. With Visual Studio 2012 you can have a simple local db that contains your data and you ping every two seconds, and you can have a LastModified date column that you could check too. This is the kind of stuff that databases and how an app interacts with a database were made for.

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking of that problem. But what if the web application save the xy-coordinates as a temp file and then as a text file when my program has read and deleted the previous text file?

Oh, really nice! I haven't gotten that far yet, but that advice is going to be much needed. I have only been trying to do simple things and do them manually to see how it is suppose to work in the end.

Thank you so much for the advice! :)

Comment: Again,this kind of read write is what databases are built for, write concurrency and high speed reads outta the box.You need a persistence layer,databases are the most robust and simple to use persistence layers in the world,why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: True, Im definately gonna use the database :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a watcher as follows:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_folder_name_)
    {
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size
    };
watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Event handler:

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Name == "TestFile.txt")
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
}
```

Alternative way is to use a `System.Threading.Timer`.

If a text is appended to the file incrementally, I recommend you to use database, sockets etc instead of file.

Comment: And yes, I think it's about time looking more into database, sockets and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the quick answer and the help! :)

Just before I saw your answer I was working on another way of doing it. The text file will be read and written to the console when the text file exists. When it's read it will be deleted and are waiting for another text file to appear (another set of xy-coordinates). I am not going to have the program to write "Waiting for new file..." in the end, it's just to see that things are working the way I've been thinking. Also I think the Web application need to receive some kind of a message that the text file is read and is now ready to receive a new text file.

Any thoughts if this is an OK way of doing it too?

```
class Testing
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string fileName = "TestFile.txt";

        while (true)
        {
            if(File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new file...");
            }

            File.Delete(fileName);               

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm new, I'm just asking to be sure. I don't know what is going to work out the best when it comes to every part of the system working together. At least I have two ways to work with now! :D